# WPF Listview Item Clicked Name

Tags: wpf, listview, selecteditem

I have a listview with 5 columns. In the first column i insert an image in wich i have an event MouseClicked event. What i want to accomplish is when i click the image from row 5 , to get the name of item in row 5 - column 2;
This is my code so far :

```
<ListView  x:Name="HistoryListB">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">

            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF515050"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF515050"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF3B3A3A"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}">

            <GridViewColumn Width="90" Header="Image" >

                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Name="Favorite" Width="12" Height="12" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn Width="90" Header="Time Added" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Time}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="110" Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="290" Header="ItemTitle" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ItemTitle}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="Duration" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Duration}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And i add items in listview like this. I have a class and a list like this  :

```
public class HistoryItems
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string ItemTitle { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public ImageSource ImageSource { get; set; }
}

IList<HistoryItems> SHistoryItems { get; set; }
```

And then add the items :

```
SHistoryItems = new List<HistoryItems>() {
    new HistoryItems () {
        Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt"),
        Status = "Started Playing : ",
        ItemTitle = StationL.StationName
    }
};

foreach (var item in SHistoryItems)
   HistoryListB.Items.Add(SHistoryItems);
```

And in my code i want to get the name of the item from same row but 2nd column :

```
private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock1.Text = ?? THE NAME OF THE SECOND COLUMN IN THE SAME ROW ?? ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Tag` property of the `Image` to hold the `HistoryItem` then you can access through the `sender` argument in the event handler.

Example:

Xaml:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Name="Favorite" Width="12" Height="12" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Tag="{Binding}" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Code:

```
private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var image = sender as Image;
    if (image != null && image.Tag is HistoryItems)
    {
       TextBlock1.Text = (image.Tag as HistoryItems).ItemTitle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That did the trick. But for some reason image.Tag is HistoryItems inside if blocks my if. I removed it, checking only if image is null and works perfect. I will gice it some more diggin. Thank you again.